# SQL Server notify web server of table change

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way of notifying a web server (in my case, a web server hosting a MVC2 webapp in C#) of the fact that there was a change to the database? The purpose is to keep the web server cache synchronized with the database.

There are polling constructs in ASP.NET that allow this, but I prefer a push system. I'm also under the assumption that the database can be manipulated by elements other than the web server itself.

My limited know-how of SQL Server/ASP MVC says that one way is through creating a table TRIGGER that pretty much hits a url which will force an update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) is the way to go, if the rate of change is moderate. For high rates of change you better poll for changes. To understand how SqlDependency works, read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). ASP already has built-in support for SqlDependency, namely the [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx). There is also [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) which adds SqlDependency capability to any arbitrary LINQ query, if possible.

Trigger is absolutely a big no-no. You cannot have database transactions wait on some URL to respond, your performance will collapse to basically nothing. Not to mention the issue of availability (updates will fail if the URL does not respond, for whatever reason).

Comment: Seems like SqlCacheDependency(SqlCommand) is what I'm looking for because it makes the effort of ensuring delivery. But you lost me by the suggestion that polling would be preferred to the query notification method. Is the cost of polling once more efficient than the test required to see if a requested query for notification has been affected by some insert/update/delete?

Comment: The cost of delivering the notification is significant. If you set up a notification solely to be immediately invalidated by the high rate of changes, you are better to simply check for the value directly. Is a fine line in which the point at which is better to poll varies from application to application, from table to table. You will have to measure and see the impact of one vs. the other, under heavy load.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the experience with it myself, but `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency` class looks like whet you need.

According to MSDN:

> SqlDependency is ideal for caching scenarios, where your ASP.NET
>   application or middle-tier service needs to keep certain information
>   cached in memory. SqlDependency allows you to receive notifications
>   when the original data in the database changes so that the cache can
>   be refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to write a CLR user-defined function (UDF) and invoke it via insert/update/delete triggers on the table(s) of interest.

The UDF should spawn a thread that signals the web server and immediately returns to the trigger. For obvious reasons, it's considered really bad form to invoke within a trigger or a running transaction any potentially long running or likely to fail operation (like accessing the network.) Unless, of course, you enjoy having the wrath of the production DBAs coming down on you like Maxwell's Silver Hammer.

Answer (score 1):

Your "limited know-how of SQL Server" is good enough. You should create an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE trigger that's going to do what you need.

Another thing is that this is a bad idea, but you're probably aware of that..

The proper way to resolve this kind of issues is to use some kind of message queue eg. MsMQ.

Answer (score 0):

To get notification from database when table content is changed/updated, you can use [`TableDependency`](https://tabledependency.codeplex.com/).

The difference with .NET `SqlDependency` is that `TableDependency` raise events containing the database table values changed / deleted / inserted.

Using `SqlDependency` you have to execute a select to get fresh data any time `SqlDependency` notify your code that something has changed on database table.

With [`TableDependency`](https://tabledependency.codeplex.com/) you can avoid that because the event you receive contains all deleted/inserted/modified values:

```
string conString = "data source=.;initial catalog=myDB;integrated security=True";

using(var tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<Customers>(conString))
{
    tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_Changed;
    tableDependency.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for receiving notifications...");
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to stop");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
...
...
void TableDependency_Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Customers> e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
    {
        var changedEntity = e.Entity;
        Console.WriteLine("DML operation: " + e.ChangeType);
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + changedEntity.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + changedEntity.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Surname: " + changedEntity.Surname);
    }
}
```